# How do I properly interpret identification on opto-isolator IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, opto-isolator

Lightning struck near my house and destroyed a bunch of things I had plugged in, including a treadmill.  I swapped parts with another one and identified that it's the lower motor control board that is the problem and on it I see an opto-isolator that had its top literally blown off.  Since I have an identical board I know the part has the following label:

```
CWN1
PC817
SHARP
```

I don't know what the CWN1 means.

TL;DR in the above label is the CWN1 important?  Is it some sort of CTR rating?  Or is it just like a manufacturer ID and I can substitute any PC817 for this one?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that the current spike which blew it's top off, didn't jump the gap to the low-voltage side (sometimes it does.)  Jellybean part; worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part number is always closest to the logo or company name and  the CWN1 = factory/date/batch codes.

### Recommendation

I recommend the PC817X3NSZ1B or PC817X4NSZ1B replacement.

Then do a diode test on all other parts or use a conservatively limited CC limited lab supply to bring up DC power externally to locate defective parts.

---

CWN1  **C means CTR = 2 to 4** = Ic=/If= 10~20mA / 5 mA = **2 to 4** @ Vce= 5V but as a switch CTR, like hFE, always reduces to << 10% CTR @ Vce(sat)
Proof: from datasheet ... Ic/If= 20mA/1mA= 0.05 @ Vce(sat)= 0.1 to 0.2V so at Vce=Vce(sat) @ Ic=1mA  CTR= 0.05/2~4= 2.5%  to 1.25%  Although the new datasheets do not show any distinction for CTR saturated vs different ranks, they do exist and will be around 10% of the max linear CTR for a fixed Vce(sat) max.  They just overdrive the LEDs to ensure low Vce(Sat) but you app might not.

**W is the factory now made by LITE-ON in China**
**N1 is the date code for 2001 January**

PC817
SHARP
still supplies them to Mouser, but they have new part numbers and they are most likely DIP for HV spacing of 5 kV **could easily have been compromised by dust and humidity.** over this period.  **No doubt this will cause a cascade of component secondary failures.**

The new stock part number uses 3 for X as Rank C  Ic= 10 to 20mA
**PC817X3NSZ1B** for DIP which are the only ones in stock at this time.

You could also use 4 as Rank D Ic= 15 to 30 mA both for If= 5mA which is slightly better and also cheaper a few cents perhaps due to high yield and more common, which is also stocked.  **PC817X4NSZ1B**

https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Sharp-Microelectronics/PC817X3NSZ1B?qs=sGAEpiMZZMv0NwlthflBi%252B9cc83UOuhhP4dcSDiySOo%3D

[image]

other misc info

There are a few other Optos rated for 5kVrms but no others at Mouser are ranked as well for CTR,  Onsemi= CTR= 1 to 6 , Everlight = 1 to 2, . Sharp makes some only in Japan also which are also good, maybe better quality PC123X5YFZ1B  where 5 is Rank N 10 to 20 mA / 5mA  similar to Rank C in the other p/n. but is non-stock. Nobody is better than Sharp in these IR optos.  Sharp IR LEDs are now licensed to Vishay.

Comment: Phenomenal!  I wasn't clear on the role of the diode test.  I'm familiar with continuity/resistance testing, but not sure in this case how to interpret the voltage drop, and wasn't sure across what should I be testing?  Capacitors, resistors, ICs?  From the low voltage side to the high voltage side?

Answer (score 6):

Probably the **rank** is "C" according to this [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/73758.pdf)

[image]

Assuming your "W" is actually a symbol representing the factory location.

As as often true in these cases, a sharp well-cropped photo is much better than an interpretation.

If so, that means that the collector current will be 10 to 20mA with LED current of 5mA, so a CTR of 200-400%.

And the full part number would be PC817x3 where x is X (through-hole), F (wide through-hole), I (gull wing), or P (gull wing tape and reel).

As @Tony points out, you can probably get what  you need from Mouser.

Comment: What is perhaps more important  is the best new part number